# sqlite return a random record in a table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How do I return a random record in a SQLite table.  For example, I have a table with 750 records, I want to return the 657th record.   (any record will do).  What would be the SQL syntax?  I have an autoincrementing field as my Id primary key, but I don want to use the key field, since the id use is not recommended. I'll be searching a db in an Android App.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Note that this approach does not scale. For every row, a random value is generated, and the table sorted by this value. In other words, it's going to be slow if there are a lot of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this that should be more efficient

```
select * from table
   where rowid =
      (select round(abs(random()/9223372036854775807.0)*max(rowid)+1) from table);
```

If you have deleted rows this select might return no rows, so if this is the case you may need to requery.